# Converting nested for loop with if conditions to Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

**I need to convert the code below from java 7 to java 8.
I tried using the class 'Optional' to simplify it but haven't succeeded implementing it.**

```
        if(replacementResponse.getGroupResponse() != null)
        {
            for(GroupCommand groupCommand : replacementResponse.getGroupResponse().getValues())
            {
                String groupQuery = groupCommand.getName();
                for(Group group : groupCommand.getValues())
                {

                    if(!group.getResult().isEmpty())
                    {
                        SolrDocumentList solrDocuments = group.getResult();

                        List<SolrDocument> documentList = null;

                        if(result.get(groupQuery) != null)
                            documentList = result.get(groupQuery);
                        else
                            documentList = new LinkedList<>();

                        for(SolrDocument solrDocument : solrDocuments)
                        {
                            documentList.add(solrDocument);
                        }

                        result.put(groupQuery, documentList);
                    }

                }
            }
            return result;

        }
        return null;
```

I tried splitting the method into 2 methods but I don't know how to implement 'Optional' inside streaming.

```
return Optional.ofNullable(replacementResponse.getGroupResponse())
                .map(replacementGroupResponse -> getGroupResponse(replacementGroupResponse.getValues())).orElse(null);

                    documentList = Optional.ofNullable(result.get(groupCommand.getName())).orElse(new LinkedList<>());


replacementGroupResponse.stream()
        .map(groupCommand -> groupCommand.getValues().stream()
                                         .filter(group -> !group.getResult().isEmpty()).
```

Comment: Please include your attempts. Without that, it looks like you think other people should do all the heavy lifting for you ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try as following to migrate your java 7 code to java 8. There might be few issues because I don't know about the implementation of many classes like SolrDocumentList,GroupCommand,Group, etc..

```
  return Optional.ofNullable(replacementResponse.getGroupResponse()).map(a -> a.getValues().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(GroupCommand::getName,groupCommand -> groupCommand.getValues().stream()
                    .flatMap(group -> group.getResult().stream()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))))).orElse(null);
```